# Відмінювати чи не відмінювати слова іншомовного походження

Tags: відмінювання, іншомовні-слова

Чому **блюдо** і **пальто** є відмінюваними іменниками іншомовного походження, а ***кіно*** - ні? Якщо брати за аналогією, то теж мало б бути відмінюваним. Адже навіть інколи чула від старших людей: "Ідем сьогодні до кІна". Чи взагалі було нормативним колись відмінювання цього слова? Якщо так, то чому зараз це невідмінюваний іменник?

Comment: Я відмінюю "кіно", "метро", "Еко", "Умберто", "Шевченко" тощо. Це природно для нашої мови. Інші українці, чия рідна мова не зіпсована сталінськими філологами, теж відмінюють такі слова. До речі, старий, не сталінський правопис задокументовує цю нашу питому рису.

Comment: Дивно, я вчилася з 1981 року (російська школа з вивченням української мови), мама з 1955 року (українська школа). І нас, і її вчили, що "пальто, кіно, метро" відмінюється: "у пальті", "у метрі".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Було б добрим тоном навести того, що *[кіно](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE)* дійсно не відмінювальне. Наприклад так:

[Чинний — 2015 — правопис](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par100p2)

> Відмінювання слів іншомовного походження
>
> **§ 100** *[…]*
>
> **2.** Деякі іменники іншомовного походження не відмінюються, а саме: іменники на **-а** з попереднім голосним: *амплуа*, *боа*, *Жоффруа*; на **-е**: *кафе*, *кашне*, *турне*; *Беранже*, *Гейне*, *Гете*, *Данте*; на **-є**: *ательє*, *Барб’є*, *Готьє*, *Лавуазьє*; на **-і**: *колібрі*, *поні*, *таксі*; *Гальвані*, *Голсуорсі*, *Россіні*, *Фірдоусі*, *Шеллі*; на **-ї**: *Віньї*, *Шантійї*; на **-о**: *бюро*, *депо*, ***кіно***, *манто*, *метро*, *радіо*; *Арно*, *Буало*, *Віардо*, *Гюго*, *Дідро*, *Лонгфелло*, *Тассо* (але ***пальто*** відмінюється); на **-йо**: *імброльйо*, *Пількомайо*; на **-у**: *какаду*, *рагу*, *Шоу*; на **-ю**: *інтерв’ю*, *меню*, *Сю*; жіночі імена на приголосний, а також жіночі прізвища на **-ін**, **-ов**: *Аліс*, *Долорес*, *Зейнаб*; (*Ельза*) *Вірхов*, (*Джеральдіна*) *Чаплін*.

*Тоді б і не переписував власноруч правопис 1940.*

## Чи було нормативним відмінювання *кіно*?

**Було —** [1928](https://r2u.org.ua/data/other/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81-1928.pdf):

> ### Рід у чужих іменниках і відмінювання їх
>
> **§ 76**. Відмінюються чужі іменники так, як відповідні українські. Зокрема,
>   відмінюються як іменники ніякого роду слова: *а́вто*, *бюро́*, *депо́*, ***кіно́***, *мо́тто*, *пальто́*, *піяні́но*, *трюмо́*, *са́го*, *ци́церо* . Зовсім не відмінюються такі слова:
>
> 1. Усі на **е**, **є**, як от: *купе́*, *неґліже́*, *декольте́*, *турне́*, *кольє́*, *Гайне́*, *Туапсе́* і т. ін.
> 2. Усі на **і**, як от: *по́ні*, *комі́*, *ра́вві*, *Поті* і т. ін.
> 3. Усі на **у**, **ю**: *какаду́*, *кенґуру́*, *інтервʼю́*, *Анжу́*, *Лупуле́ску* і т. ін.
> 4. *бру́тто*, *не́тто*, *по́рто*, *со́льо*, *трі́о*, *фра́нко*, *са́льдо*, *ра́діо* (від *радіо* можливо й *радіом*) і т. ін.

[Проєкт 1999](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83_1999_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) **передбачав** таке:

> **Запропоновано:** Відмінювати іноземні запозичення на **-о**, крім тих, у яких перед **-о** є інші голосні.
>
> **Причина зміни:** Їхня відмінюваність у живому мовленні, в літературній мові до «реформи» 1933 р., у творах деяких нинішніх письменників. Незмінюваність їх руйнує відмінювання питомих українських іменників на **-о** (наприклад, неправильне «*брати Сірко*», а треба «*брати́ Сірки*»).
>
> **Приклади:** *Пальто* — *пальта*, *метро* — *метра́*, але *радіо* — *радіо* (бо є голосна перед **-о**)

Тут і бачимо наступну…

## Чому зараз невідмінюваний іменник?

… згадку про [1933](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1933_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83). Отже зміна дійсно відбулась десь за совітські часи. Правда, особисто знаходжу не *[там](http://lib.movahistory.org.ua/PRAWOPYS/UP_33.djvu)* чи в [подальших](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/585), а в [1940](http://lib.movahistory.org.ua/PRAWOPYS/UP_40_p.djvu), а саме:

> Відмінювання слів іншомовного походження
>
> **§ 100** *[…]*
>
> **2.** Деякі  іменники  Іншомовного  походження  не  відмінюються,  а  саме:
>
> - на  **-а**  (в  загальних  Іменах —  з  попереднім  голосним),  напр.:  *амплуа́*,  *боа́*,  *Во́льта*, *Дюма́*,  *Жоффруа́*;
> - на  **-е**,  напр.:  *кашне́*,  *ко́фе* {при слові *кава* — *від себе*},  *турне́*,  *Беранже́*,  *Ге́йне*,  *Ге́те*,  *Да́нте*;
> - на  **-є**,  напр.:  *ательє́*,  фойє́ {коли немає *є*, але хочеться вставити *й* — *від себе*},  *Барбʼє*,́  *Готьє́*,  *Лавуазьє́*;
> - на  **-I**,  напр.:  *колі́брі*,  *по́ні*,  *таксі́*,  *Гальва́ні*,  *Го́лсуорсі*, *Россі́ні*, *Фірдо́усі*,  *Ше́ллі*;
> - на  **-ї**,  напр.:  *Віньї́*,  *Шантійї́*;
> - на  **-о**,  напр.:  *авто́*, *бюро́*, *депо́*, *кіло́*,  ***кіно́***, *манто́*, *метро́*, *пальто́*, *ра́діо*,  *Арно́*,  *Буало́*,  *Віардо́*,  *Гюго́*,  *Дідро́*,  *Лонгфе́лло*,  *Та́ссо*;
> - на  **-йо**,  напр.:  імбрбльйо,  ПількомАйо;
> - на  **-у**,  напр.:  *какаду́*,  *рагу́*,  *Шо́у*;
> - на  **-ю**,  напр.:  *інтерв'ю́*, *меню́*, *Сю*;
> - на  **-я**  (прізвища),  напр.:  *Го́йя*,  *Золя́*.

*Недарма згадував, що не був б змушений переписувати. Тут тїльки **пальто** невідміннювальне і нема згадки жіночі прізвищ. Сміховино і цїкаво, шчо »пальто« стало особливим шче з [1945](http://korchiwjaka.blogspot.com/2013/01/1945-1945.html)*

Не дивно, шчо так є в [московській мові](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1216-1231.html#1221):

> **§ 1221.** Нулевым называется склонение, парадигма которого состоит из омонимичных форм с нулевой флексией: им. п.: *боа*, *депо*, *фойе*; род. п. *боа*, *депо*, *фойе*; дат. п. *боа*, *депо*, *фойе*; вин. п.: *боа*, *депо*, *фойе*; тв. п.: *боа*, *депо*, *фойе*; *предл*. п.: о *боа*, о *депо*, о *фойе*. К нулевому склонению принадлежат следующие слова.
>
> **1)** Многие оканчивающиеся на гласные существительные иноязычного происхождения, называющие неодушевленные предметы, лиц мужского пола и животных: ***[пальто](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE)***, ***[кино](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE)***, *метро*, *шоссе*, *кашне*, *пенсне*, *рагу*, *боа*, *буржуа*, *па*, *баккара*, *бра*, *фа* (муз. нота), *антраша*, *кенгуру*, *интервью*, *алоэ*, *шимпанзе*, *фойе*, *ателье*, *кофе*, *какао*, *манго*, *банджо* (муз. инструмент), *радио*, *барокко*, *либретто*, *алиби*, *жалюзи*, *янки*, *кули*, *пенни*.