# "Кіна" чи "кіно" не буде?

Tags: словосполучення, орфографія, відмінювання

Часто зустрічала фразу "*кіна не буде*", тому вирішила з`ясувати, як буде правильно.

[§ 111. ВІДМІНЮВАННЯ СЛІВ ІНШОМОВНОГО ПОХОДЖЕННЯ](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/111.html) містить правило:

> Не відмінюємо іменники іншомовного походження з кінцевими:
>
> о (коли перед ним стоїть інший голосний): ра́діо, Онта́ріо, Бази́ліо,
>   Ма́ріо, але пальто́ — пальта́, пальто́м, (у) пальті́; так само б’юро́,
>   депо́, **кіно́**, метро́, ситро́;

Неодноразово зустрічала фразу "кіна не буде", особливо у новинах від каналу "СТБ", зокрема, у [випуску від 14.12.2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRXHOuEvAqA).

Таке формулювання присутнє і на [radiosvoboda](https://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/953871.html).

Ця форма активно вживається у літературі, наприклад, [тут](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1042243/30/Keshelya_-_Osin_Velikih_Nebes%2C_abo_Pririchanski_harakteri.html) .

*То яке написання "кіна не буде" чи "кіно не буде" слід вважати правильним?*

Comment: @bytebuster Перевідкрив питання, оскільки контекст ширший за вживання літературної норми.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Якщо говорити про літературну мову, то правильним буде "кіно не буде" (і як справедливо зазначив bytebuster відповідь на це питання є тут: [Відмінювати чи не відмінювати слова іншомовного походження](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3319/69)). Але у цьому випадку фраза побудована не за правилами літературної мови.

"Кіна не буде" - це цитата з фільму "Джентельмени удачі" (повністю її можна перекласти як "Кіна не буде - електрика скінчилась"), де вона звучить з вуст злочинця-рецидівіста і побудована з порушенням норм літературної мови (як слово "кіно" так і комбінація "електрика скінчилась"). Тому при перекладі на українську мову не доцільно приводити фразу до норм літературної української мови, бо зникне сам ефект заради якого ця фраза і цитується.

Власне в обох наведених вами випадках контекст вживання цієї цитати поєднує як буквальний аспект - що канал телебачення або процес дублювання кіно ("кіна") який може перестати транслюватися/діяти ("не буде") із правовим аспектом, який автори вважають несправедливим (у оригіналі фразу говорить злочинець).

Comment: Якщо ви (слушно) стверджуєте, що *«…не доцільно приводити фразу до норм літературної української мови»*, то як са́ме пропонуєте перекладати? Адже відповідь має містити пряму відповідь або, принаймні, варіанти.

Comment: Переклад "кіна не буде" - вже є у питанні.